# Android Custom ROM Missing “Add Google Account” Option

Tags: custom-roms, google-account

In the customized Android system, all pre-installed google apps are missing and it's not allowed to add google account. I downloaded the Gapps from http://goo.im/gapps, but I cannot install the apps due to signature issue

Is there other possible way to retrieve the "add google account" option back?

Thanks

**Update:**

I wasn't aware that I need to push the Gapps into /system/app to avoid signature problem. When I did, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty normal for (almost) all Custom ROMs: They are not *permitted* to include Google Apps. GApps are proprietary, and to ship them bundled with *anything* requires an explicit license from Google.

However, Custom ROMs come rooted usually. and also usually, you (at least in most cases) have a custom recovery when installing them. So if you feel you need a way, you've got two choices primarily:

- pick the GApps package corresponding to your Android version from [Goo.im](http://goo.im/gapps), and flash them via your custom recovery, or
- head over to XDA and check for the [NOGAPPS packages](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1715375) if you prefer an open-source replacement

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps (Gapps) is the only way to sync with Google. Whatcustom ROM have you downloaded, and which device do you own? Try to find Gapps installation somewhere else.

Comment: I built my own ROM from the source code. And I am using Nexus 4. I wonder if I need to add something into the source code before re-compile

Comment: If this question is about programming, try to ask at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) (I know that SO don't specialize in Android Dev, but they have the "android" tag.)
Alternatively, you can try to ask in [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/), great forum.